# How can I solve this error logits and labels must have the same first dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, shapes

this is my first time working with neural networks. After fitting my code I had this error:

**logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [4,4096] and labels shape [16384]
     [[node loss/activation_27_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits 
(defined at C:\Users\admin\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_8265]
Function call stack:
distributed_function**

Can you help please why I get this error, here is my code:

```
batch_size = 5
learning_rate = 0.8
no_classes = 1
no_epochs = 3
validation_split = 0.2
verbosity = 0
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.keras 
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import pickle
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization


pickle_in = open("X.pickle","rb")
X= pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("Y.pickle","rb")
Y = pickle.load(pickle_in)

# Y=Y/255

img_rows=img_cols=64

if K.image_data_format()== 'channels_first':
    X = np.array(X).reshape(np.array(X).shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    Y= np.array(Y).reshape(np.array(Y).shape[0], 1, img_rows, img_cols)
    print(X.shape)
    print(Y.shape)
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    X = np.array(X).reshape(np.array(X).shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    Y = np.array(Y).reshape(np.array(Y).shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, 1)
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols,1)    

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
print(input_shape)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),input_shape=input_shape,padding="same"))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64*64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X,Y,
          batch_size=5,
          epochs=no_epochs,
          verbose=verbosity,
          validation_split=validation_split)
score = model.evaluate(X,Y, batch_size=5)
```

I don't know what to do I've been struggling with this error

Comment: What is the output when you run `print(Y.shape)`. Reshaping X is correct but we should not reshape Y.

Comment: If the data `X.pickle, Y.pickle` can be shared, I can try to provide the solution.

Comment: Hi @Chaimanejjam, can you please include details about your training datasets (ie. shape)?

Answer (score 1):

Error was occuring due to use of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function, please replace this with `categorical_crossentropy`.

Please replace your `model.complie` block with below

```
model.compile(loss=tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```